# Netsuite custom html case form - where does it go?

Tags: html, netsuite

I have several forms on my website, and currently working on replacing these forms with Netsuite's forms.
To do so I create an html template for each form, using Netsuite's nl tags.

The requirement is to save the submissions of each form separately, but I don't know how to make it appear under a certain list, everything goes under 'leads'.
I may be missing something since I'm not entirely familiar with Netsuite's terminology regarding lists,cases, etc.

Answer (score 0):

NetSuite already has Case, Customer and Email forms and if you have separate list then you can create Custom record and use online form under that record and public that form so it will be stored separately on your custom record.

Hope this help.

Regards,
Mayur